# How can i run node js in the in the integrated vs code terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

when i use 'node -v' in command prompt or the terminal it outputs 'v19.8.1'
but when i use 'node -v' in the integrated vs code terminal it outputs this error

```
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node -v
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

is there any way to fix this issue

i tried using command prompt instead of powershell as the integrated terminal in vs code but that didnt work

Comment: I think you've run powershell, but wanted cmd or bash

Comment: Compare your `PATH` variable in the one where it works vs. the one where it doesn't by running `echo $PATH` in each. Looks like it's not getting set up in the integrated terminal. Maybe it's running a different shell environment? (bash vs. zsh or whatever?)

Comment: It's probably an issue with your `PATH`, like @ray said. Try restarting VS Code to refresh your shell if you just installed node